# Error accessing resources while using routes Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, routes

At **home** page, i can access the resources like bootstrap, javascript and image then from home refer to **news** page then from newspage, it refers to **newsDetail** page. But in this **newsDetails** page, it access the wrong address of resources.
Example :
in Homepage, it correctly access 
http://localhost:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://localhost:8000/img/Logo.png

but in newsDetails page, it access http://localhost:8000/news/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://localhost:8000/news/img/Logo.png

It has the following 'news' on the address.
This is my routes

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@showHome');
Route::get('news','NewsController@showNews');
Route::get('news/{id}','NewsController@showNewsDetails');
```

Controller

```
public function showNewsDetails($id)
    {
        $content = News::find($id);
        return view('newsDetails',compact('content'));
    }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: show your view code

Comment: show your code where you add bootstrap.min.css and Logo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place all of CSS/JS stuff into public folder and you can access it using `asset()` helper

```
<link href = "{{ asset('public') }}/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
```

For logo

```
<img src="{{ asset('public') }}/img/Logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset) helper to avoid this kind of problems:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/Logo.png') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `url()` helper:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('/website/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

Or use `/` at the beginning of your link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/website/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses HTTPs (which most do today):

Use [`secure_asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-secure-asset) or [`secure_url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-secure-url):

> The secure_asset function generates a URL for an asset using HTTPS:
>
> The secure_url function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the given path:

**Try:**

```
$url = secure_asset('img/Logo.png');

$url = secure_url('user/profile');
```